# How to read sms of some specific numbers in android

Tags: android

How can i read `SMS` of some specific number (more than 1 number) from inbox. Please help.
Give something idea about it,or any reference.
i have tried a code but not work.

Comment: By using Contentprovider, you can get it(Just add a condition for that specific number in WHERE param).

Comment: In ContentProvider query just write condition in where clause and you will get consitional result whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that you can get the your SMS in to content provider with the use of content resolver like...

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
String where = "address="+phone_no;
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] { "_id", "thread_id"}, where, null,null);





    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                long thread_id = cursor.getLong(1);
                where = "thread_id="+thread_id;
                Uri thread = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
             // write your Logic code here
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/07/receive-sms-using-android.html)

Using following lines you will get sender Number of the SMS..

```
SmsMessage SMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
String sender = SMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
```

In `SignInWaitingActivity.java` using condition you can check specific senders number..

Happy coding,,!!!